# A practical guide to Amazon Echo, families with children?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I have an Amazon account, as does my wife. We share Amazon Prime through household setup, and have added our daughter to our kids list. We purchased an Echo Dot for our daughter, and are likely going to get a few more for around the house.

The confusion lies in how to set this up for **her**. She can't have an Amazon account apparently, so not sure how to even setup the new intercom features, etc. The only way I've seen so far is I have to set it up under my name.

I'd like for her to be able to have her own reminders, calendar, features, etc.

Can someone please outline a practical way to set this up? I'd rather not sign into my Amazon account and be blasted with advertisements for all the new Pop songs or things to buy, based on her usage of the echo.

**Update**
In comments:

> It would help for non-experts if you're specific about what prevents user specific accounts, or prevents you setting up a sockpuppet account

On the apparent issues, or what I ran into was when setting up the echo for the first time, it would not allow me to select my child's account in the list, only mine or my wife's. Sockpuppet? As in a fake account? Was hoping to avoid that route :)

Comment: It would help for non-experts if you're specific about what _prevents_ user specific accounts, or prevents you setting up a sockpuppet account.

Comment: To add to this, I'm not sure if you can have more than 2 adults in a household

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this [1] article from 2015 it tells:

> To use multiple accounts with Echo, you’ll need to set up an Amazon Households account, which allows two adults in the same house to share Prime benefits, and allows parents to share content with up to four children. Amazon says it’s not supporting children’s accounts on Echo at the moment, however.
>
> As ZDNet notes, families can now say “Alexa, switch accounts” to cycle between the two adult account holders.

If situation does not have changed, children are blocked by restrictions.

[1] http://www.techhive.com/article/2977784/connected-home/new-update-makes-amazon-echo-more-family-friendly.html